# How can I use the output of my Localhost in Wie website?

Tags: java, localhost, frontend, backend, ssh-tunnel

I have a localhost from my java backend, and it gives the Json output on the Localhost.
how can I simply show this information in the Localhost on the Wie Website?
how should I define it to get them from my localhost?

What I am already doing is:

- Create a Localhost  from my Java code (RestAPI)
- tunnel to internet with the help of https://ngrok.com/ and expose the JSON output of my code on the internet.
- then create a website on Wix and fetch it.

I am wondering if there is another way if I can simply buy space on wix and have my java backend also on this space online?? or the backend code should always be connected through such process to the online frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Wix Fetch](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-fetch/fetch) to call your localhost endpoint just like you would any other endpoint. Or are you looking for something else?

For calling localhost on Wix websites always make the call from the browser (public file or page) not the backend.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as you said the simplest way for me is:
1- tunnel to for example through https://ngrok.com/ and expose the JSON out put of my code on the internet
2-then create a website on wix and fetch it

I am wondering if there is another way if I can simply buy  space on wix and have my  java backend also on this space online?? or the backend code should always be connected through such process to the online frontend?